# Convert video link to m3u8

Tags: mp4, http-live-streaming, live, m3u8, iptv

I want to convert a video link to an m3u8 file
That means I can give a video for the input of the link and I can watch the same video with the extension m3u8 for the output.
Glad to help me

Comment: You can use this https://anyconv.com/mp4-to-m3u8-converter/

Comment: What is this "video link"?  FFmpeg can deal with most things...

Comment: @Brad I mean the video url like: example.com/test.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Use ffmpeg to convert files to M3U8 and then host it anywhere to get the site and use it for watching too

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can this be done in php?  If possible, give it a code